# How to change a label_tag to a drop down in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a rails app Where I have users who belong to a school that has many classrooms.

users create a pin in an associated classroom and use a code to ensure they're associating the pin in the correct classroom. Right now I have this working with a text field but I need to switch to a drop down that lists all the classroom codes. I'm having trouble figuring this out. (new to RoR).

Here's the part of the form I need to change form for creating a pin:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <%= label_tag(:classroom, "Enter your classroom code:") %>
   <input type="text" name="pin[code]">
</div>
```

Classroom model:

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :school
belongs_to :teacher, :class_name => "User"
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

has_many :pins
has_many :reflections

validates_presence_of :school
validates_presence_of :teacher
validates :code, :uniqueness => { :scope => :school_id }


end
```

Pin Model

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :classroom
has_and_belongs_to_many :emotions

validates_presence_of :user
validates_presence_of :classroom

end
```

Pin controller

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
respond_to :html

def search
  index
  render :index
  authorize @pins
end

def home
 @pins = Pin.all
 respond_with(@pins)
 authorize @pins
end

def show
 respond_with(@pin)
end

def new
  @pin = Pin.new
  @emotions = Emotion.all 
  @school = School.find(params[:school])
  respond_with(@pin)
  authorize @pin
end

def edit
end

def create
  code = params[:pin][:code]
  @classroom = Classroom.where('code LIKE ?', code).first
  unless @classroom
    flash[:error] = "Classroom code incorrect"
    render :new
  else
  params[:pin][:classroom_id] = @classroom.id
  end


  @pin = Pin.new(pin_params)
  @pin.save
  params[:pin][:emotion_ids].each do |emotion_id| 
    @emotion = Emotion.find(emotion_id)
    @pin.emotions << @emotion
  end
  if @pin.save
    redirect_to signout_path and return 
  end 
  respond_with(@pin)
  authorize @pin

end

def update
  @pin.update(pin_params)
  respond_with(@pin)
  authorize @pin
end

def destroy
  @pin.destroy
  respond_with(@pin)
  authorize @pin
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`select_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) helper to create a dropdown select box in rails. You can do something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label_tag(:classroom, "Select your classroom code:") %>
  <%= select_tag "pin[code]", options_from_collection_for_select(Classroom.all, "code", "code") %>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I got this to work yesterday by just copy and pasting your code but for some reason now i'm getting an error saying the code is empty even though I have it selected. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3787971 good to hear that it worked for you and for your second problem i need to see logs to better understand what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I fixed it. Got a little messy in the controller create method. Just needed a little refactoring.